# Get load time of each page with ember

Tags: ember.js

I want to calculate the page load time using Ember. I know how to do in javascript . But I don't know how to possible in Ember. Do anyone know ?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using the [ready event](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#event_ready) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rokom/1/) of using the Application's ready event:

```
var date = new Date();
App = Ember.Application.create({

  ready: function(){
    console.log(new Date() - date);
  }
});
```

Comment: I didn't get the page refresh time. The ready function calls only the window load.

Comment: Can you define what is page refresh time? I assumed it to be (the time needed for loading the first script minus the time taken to completely display the DOM)

Comment: If I click a link it redirects to another page . Here I didn't get the navigated page's load time.